# ax.set_xticklabels doesn't work correctly in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to replace the default x-tick labels with my year sequence, using this code:

```
plt.plot(np.median(trans_es, axis=0))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(list(range(2003, 2019)))
plt.show()
```

However, Matplotlib returns this figure to me:

[image]

It doesn't start with 2003, neither does it end in 2018.
How can I correct this problem?

EDIT: This problem remains even I change the `np.median(trans_es, axis=0)` part to `range(16)`

Comment: Try making the figsize bigger. My guess is 2003 and 2012+ can't fit.

Comment: `plt.plot(x,y)` should take both x and y as input. Then you would already get the correct scale out. Then you need to use `ax.set_xticks` to set the tick positions. Only then you may use `ax.set_xticklabels` to customize the labels.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You're right! This works for me.